# How to increase QT Gui thread priority in linux

Tags: linux, qt, qthread

Is there a way to set gui thread priority higher than others threads of my app in Linux? 
I also know that setPriority function in QThread class, not working in linux. 
however, is there a solution to do it?
(i am working with qt4.8)
thanks a lot

Comment: Since you have access to the sourcecode you just could pause your threads which results in more time for gui thread.

Comment: i cant do this. because i have another thread that working with socket and get data from network. my program should be able to receive data at any time. as throughput of my socket is high (get image from socket and show on gui), sometimes my gui thread working slowly and in some cases my gui be freeze

Comment: Having a higher priority gui thread would result in the other thread being paused. So its no difference if you manually pause your thread (msecs) or the scheduler pauses your thread

Comment: if the gui thread freezes then it is blocking on something that it shouldn't often caused by a bad design

Comment: My recommendation run you application in [PROFILER](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-valgrind-overview.html) to find source of problems. I'm for 95% sure that you simply have faulty code.

Comment: The suggested dupe isn't the best target - see [QThread::start(priority) vs Linux](/q/55258248/4850040) for one that accurately describes the state of `setPriority()` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do that. Your GUI should only be displaying the most recent image. Most likely your design forces the GUI to display the outdated images even if they are not relevant anymore.

The typical way this would be achieved in Qt is by having an image viewer class that only displays the most recently set image:

```
class ImageViewer : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QImage m_img;
    bool m_new;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.drawImage(0, 0, m_img);
        m_new = false;
    }
public:
    ImageViewer(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), m_new(false) {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    }
    Q_SLOT void setImage(const QImage & img) {
        if (m_new) qDebug() << "Viewer dropped frame!";
        m_img = img;
        m_new = true;
        if (m_img.size() != size()) setFixedSize(m_img.size());
        update();
    }
};
```

You can then send signals connected to the `setImage` slot. Those signals can come from a `QObject` that has been moved to another thread.

See [here for a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253353/1329652).

Answer (score 0):

In GUI thread (for example in `main()`) execute:

```
QThread::currentThread()->setPriority(QThread::HighPriority);
```

See Qt docs for more possible priority values.

Comment: As i said, i working qt under linux. see again Qt docs for setPriority function ----> The effect of the priority parameter is dependent on the operating system's scheduling policy. In particular, the priority will be ignored on systems that do not support thread priorities (such as on Linux, see http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler for more details).

Comment: @hossein if you read that page that the Qt documentation links to you will see that it says: "The scheduling policy and parameters are in fact per-thread attributes on Linux."  This seems to disagree with the note that Qt makes about Linux.  I haven't figured out for sure who is right yet but the Qt documentation seems questionable on this point.