# QT slot not getting called on main thread

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread

From the thread context of a slot in my QT GUI application (upon button push), I am trying to launch a worker thread to update other another part of the GUI with the results of a CPU intensive calculation - these results will update a table or a google like map widget - so this needs to occur in the main QT application thread where it is safe to update these widgets.

The problem I have is that the `updateGUIWidget` slot never gets called unless I change the connection type to `Qt::DirectConnection` - in which case it gets called in the worker thread (where it is unsafe to update the GUI).  I checked the results of each of the connect calls and they are fine, it seems that there is some issue with the event loop somewhere.  I'm not sure if I need to allocate the thread and the worker objects as members of the mainwindow or if its OK to do so from stack variables in the slot.

```
void
mainwindow::on_importSimulatedFlight_clicked()
{
    // experimental worker thread model adapted from YouTube tutorial
    // by Giuseppe di Angelo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgqT6SIeRn4
    // auto thread = new QThread;
    // note worker created in gui thread here - we will move its thread
    // affinity to 'thread' below before starting it.
    auto thread = new QThread;
    auto worker = new Worker;
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    // connect(worker, &Worker::progressUpdate, this, &mainwindow::updateGUIWidget, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(worker, &Worker::progressUpdate, this, &mainwindow::updateGUIWidget, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(worker, &Worker::workDone, thread, &QThread::quit);
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
    // move worker to separate thread
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}
```

The mainwindow has a slots declared in mainwindow.h as follows:

```
class mainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit mainwindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~mainwindow();
    ...
public slots:
    void on_importSimulatedFlight_clicked();
    void updateGUIWidget(const param& rParam);
    ...
}
```

and implemented in mainwindow.cpp as follows:

```
void
mainwindow::updateGUIWidget(const param& rParam)
{
... update widget components with rParam partial result here
}
```

and my worker is as follows:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        const QString result;
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            const MMRTimedRecord foo;
//            QThread::sleep(1);
            emit progressUpdate(foo);
        }
        emit workDone(result);
    }
signals:
    void progressUpdate(const MMRTimedRecord&);
    void workDone(const QString &result);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because there's a serious flaw in your code: you are trying to emit a reference to a local variable to be handled in an slot on a different thread. That is a recipe for disaster.

When you are using `Qt::QueuedConnection`, you MUST emit by value, like this:

`void progressUpdate(MMRTimedRecord val);`

That means that your MMRTimedRecord must be copyable, and correspondingly, your slot must also accept by value. And why is there a mismatch between the signal `progressUpdate(const MMRTimedRecord&)` and the slot `updateGUIWidget(const param& rParam);` ?

Comment: actually I just figured out that I can call qRegisterMetaType <MMRTimedRecord>("MMRTimedRecord"); and it works fine.  I noticed a console message  indicating that the type needed to be registered (presumably in order to be serialized via a queued connection) - my question incorrectly named the (const param& rParam) it should have been const (MMRTimedRecord& rParam)

Comment: You still can't emit by reference if the event handler is in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988826/running-code-in-the-main-loop/51515954#51515954) for a possible solution. You can do

```
MainThreadEvent::post([&]()
  {
    // gui update stuff
  }
);
```

in your slot to do the gui update in the main thread, but it is a crude approach to be sure. Despite this, I do something like this all the time. Be careful of dangling pointers and references (use `QPointer`)..., as the issued event is independent of the issuing object. Alternatively, use the timer approach.

Answer (score 0):

It’s really easy – and you shouldn’t be managing any threads manually:

```
void Ui::slot() {
  QtConcurrent::run([this]{
    auto result = compute();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, [this, r = std::move(result)]{
      m_widget.setSomething(r);
    });
  });
}
```

The type of the data you compute should be movable.