# Can I call update() function of a QT widget directly in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Since update() function will not repaint QT widget directly, it is just schedule a event for later process, so is it safe to call it in worker thread? My thread is a boost::thread, not QThread. I find it seems work but sometimes the widget will not receive any paintEvent. I do not know if it is because of my direct update() call.

Comment: It seems the same question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420917/using-qwidgetupdate-from-non-gui-thread

Comment: There's no reason ever to do that. When you modify the contents of the widget, the widget should automatically update itself.